# SAP GUI VBA Reference

Tags: vba, reference, sap-gui

I have the following error in a VBA function.

It says this is an invalid syntax here:

```
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
```

Do I need any reference for this? I have SAP GUI 7.30.

Comment: What version of office do you use? ..bits and 20.. ? Take a look here : http://scn.sap.com/message/13876230#13876230

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The problem is that when I run through windows cmd or manually double-click the .vbs file, it works great. However, running from groovy (java) I get the error. I'm really lost on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe SAPGUI scripting should work with Office 2013 - I assume you've reviewed the sample applications in [note 1441550](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1441550)? Scripting reference documentation is [available](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-8971?rid=/webcontent/uuid/007084d7-41f4-2a10-9695-d6bce1673c2f) from SDN.

**Note:** Don't forget - for scripting to work, you need to enable the `sapgui/user_scripting` or `user_scripting_per_user` profile parameters (this will be done by your system administrator,  using transactions `RZ10` or `RZ11`) as well as enable it in your SAPGUI settings (*Accessibility & Scripting* > *Scripting*)

[image: sapgui/user_scripting]

[image: SAPGUI 7.40 Scripting Options]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What is happening is that it is trying to get a handle on an existing COM object (`GetObject`) instead of creating one (`CreateObject`).

The solution was as simple as having a running SAP GUI instance before launching the script.